# Dynamically updating row values based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am running a simulation test where I want to dynamically change some values present in rows for each column based on certain set of conditions

**The Problem Statement**

1. My dataset has 400 rows and my first test case is to update 5% of the rows in each column, so 5% of 400  = 20 rows which needs to be updated
2. These 20 rows should be only updated for the top 5 categories that are present in my dataset. So 4 rows each which needs to be updated

My dataframe looks like this:

```
A     B     C    D      Category
1     10    3    4      X
4     9     6    9      Y
9     3     7    10     XX
10    1     9    7      YY
10    1     9    7      ZZ
10    1     9    7      YZZ
10    1     9    7      YZZ
10    1     9    7      YYYY
                        ......400 rows
```

**The conditions are:**

1. While updating the rows I would want to make sure that 20 rows (5% of the overall dataset) should be updated only where the top 5 categories are encountered. In my case the top 5 categories are `X, Y , XX, YY and ZZ`. These rows should be updated to value 7 where the previous value was 1,2,3,4,5,6

The resultant datframe should look like this:

```
A     B     C    D      Category
7     10    7    7      X
7     9     7    9      Y
9     7     7    10     XX
10    7     9    7      YY
10    7     9    7      ZZ
10    1     9    7      YZZ
10    1     9    7      YZZ
10    1     9    7      YYYY
                        ......400 rows
```

In the resultant dataframe, there is no impact on the categories which are not the top 5 categories, this case `YZZ or YYYY` and to demonstrate an example I can't show all the updated rows but for example in the above dataframe, 2 rows have been updated for column A where previous value was <=6 to a new value 7 and similarly the other two rows will get updated to 7 wherever the condition is met.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following logic:

```
# get only desired Categories
m = df['Category'].isin(['X', 'Y', 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'])

# select 20 random rows from the above 
idx = df[m].sample(n=20).index

# replace the 1 ≤ values ≤ 6 by 7
df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].mask(df.loc[idx].ge(1)&df.loc[idx].le(6), 7)
```

If you rather want 4 rows per Category, use this variant for the random sampling:

```
idx = df[m].groupby('Category').sample(n=4).index
```